# Explode and foreach to create multi <td> table

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach, html-table

I'm using `explode()` to basically take apart paragraphs into individual words. Works great. The looping through with a `foreach()`. Also works great.  Nothing complicated here.

```
$title_pieces = explode(" ", $title_fixed);
foreach($title_pieces as $tpiece){
echo "<b>$tpiece<br>";
}
```

Unfortunately this returns just an ugly long list of words.  What I'd like to do but can't quite figure out how is to put this all in a nice table.  Creating the table is no problem, the part I can't figure out is how to get it to write more than one `$tpiece` per row.   I'd like to have maybe 5 `<td>`s in each row.

So if I do:

```
foreach($title_pieces as $tpiece){
echo "<tr><td>$tpiece</td></tr>";
}
```

I'm still just left with a long list.  Can someone point me in the right direction here.

Comment: Don't put a closing and opening tr in each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a sample-code. Work around with the `modulo`-operator.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
echo '<table><tr>';
foreach($title_pieces as $tpiece){
    if ($i % 10 == 0)
        echo "</tr><tr>";

    echo "<td>$tpiece</td>";

    $i++;
}

echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Upvote for you sir. Edit: that weird edit is wrong.

Comment: You have the tr's echo twice. Should be table?

Comment: The new lines after conditions that only serve to confuse noob developers

Comment: @jimjimmy1995: Nope. Because 1/10 is not 0, the first <tr> will not be echoed the first loop. Placing <td> without <tr> is wrong. The final </tr> is to close the row if the last element does not do it.

Comment: I still like this answer but the last row may have a mistmatched amount of cells.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I've never actually used that and had no idea. Learn something new every day, at least hopefully!

Comment: @OptimusCrime Ah I see now. I'm a bit tired. :P

Comment: @TheEditor: I had some stupid mistakes in my code. It is working now ;) Tested.

Comment: @popnoodles: Sorry to confuse you. I've fixed and tested the code now. You were right, I did some silly mistakes.

Comment: I think the code now will be not have a `</table>` tag if there are an even multiple of ten items. You don't need the last check with your current loop implementation.

Comment: @OptimusCrime you're being facetious or naive or both but never mind.

Comment: You still might be missing a </tr> but that's not fatal, I guess. You just don't need that last modulo test after you changed your loop. There will always be an open table row when you get to the end.

Comment: @OptimusCrime works great. I was making an unholy mess trying to get this to work.  Thanks again all.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$count = 1;
echo "<tr>";
foreach($title_pieces as $tpiece){
    if ($count % NUM_COLS == 0)
         echo "</tr><tr>";

    echo "<td>$tpiece</td>";
    $count++;
}
echo "</tr>";
```

There's probably a clever optimization in there. What you are doing is counting the number of cells and starting a new row when the count divides NUM_COLS evenly. It's important count starts on 1, not 0, or you'll have an empty row.